How to see / view the Android vector drawable XML?
How can I visually see a picture from an Android vector drawable XML?
I disassembled the Apk-file, and now I want to replace the icons, but how can I visually see them in the code. Is there a program that can translate the code:
android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>


into the SVG picture?

You can easily preview pathdata like this in webapps like svg-editor. Jus copy/paste the pathData string. Otherwise you can create a SVG with a <path> element and set the pathdata to a d attribute

@denbon, thanking on StackOverflow is done by upvoting and by answer accepting. If you are satisfied with my answer below, please mark it as accepted on the left side from the answer and / or upvote it. You will also get 2 points of reputation for this action. Or you could write some comments.

You code is written in «Android vector drawable» XML format. But it is not the SVG format. You could convert it into SVG format. If you know good enough the SVG format you can convert it into SVG by your self, or you could use the online applications, which can do it:

Shapeshifter App. Use import an export buttons.
Floo App

But be carefully! If you have in your code something like this:
android:fillColor="@color/colorLightYellow"

you have to change it to:
android:fillColor="#fcab29"

before you use this tools. The «Floo App» could do this automatically by most of colors. See also this my answer about colors.
And than if you have converted it into SVG you can view and edit the SVG file in each SVG editor.
But without the converting you could view and edit the paths from Android vector drawable (and SVG paths too) in Online SVG path editor.
For example you have this code:
<android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>

And from this code you have to copy and paste only this path part:
M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z

into the SVG path editor. By SVG paths is the same.
